# How to set up testing back end for PHP cURL

Tags: php

I don't have much experience here, so pls bear with me. I am good with cURL and sending data to API's - right now I want to set up a testing environment as the API isn't ready, but I know what he responses will be.

I will be sending some data to the API via cURL - no issue there. The main variable is called $src and it is a simple POST value. I want to set up a script on another server and echo back some messaging based on $src value. 
On the remote script, that will mimic the API I'm getting returned messages like "Resource id #4" or "Resource id #5" I realize that is a generic message. Here is what I am trying to do

cURL scripting

```
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');
$urlFX = 'http://myserver.com/NTLM/testresponse.php';
$ch = curl_init($urlFX);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($ch);
```

Test script to mimic API Response:

```
<?php
    $src = $_GET['src'];
    if($src == "nt-fx-data-test") {
        echo('foo');
    } else {
        echo('bar');
    }
?>
```

How can I set up a script that will mimic the API's responses based on the $src var value?

Comment: how are you hitting the php file? Are you using a webserver?

Comment: Yes, I'm just storing it on a different server and POST'ing to it via cURL

Comment: Where does `Resource id #x` comes from?

Comment: Can you show an example of a curl command line and the response you expect?

Comment: Is this a typo? You indicate you send a POST request but you try to get the variable from $_GET.

Comment: Resource id #x is what is being returned - although it's nowhere in my script. I searched and it seems to be some type of error msg from PHP?

Comment: Resource id #x is the handle of the curl object - don't you want to echo $output

Comment: @DavidBray- that did it, an oversight on my part. Now my issue is why is the Test API script echo'ing 'bar'? The $src value is 'nt-fx-data-test'

Comment: take note of @ChristianLescuyer tip - use $_POST - not $_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hit

```
http://goelette.net/NTLM/testresponse.php
```

With params:

- src=nt-fx-data-test
- src=xp
- dst=nt-fx-data-test

Code:

```
<?php
foreach($_REQUEST as $param => $value) {
    if ($param == 'src' and $value == 'nt-fx-data-test') {
        echo 'foo';
    } else if ($param == 'src' and $value != 'nt-fx-data-test') {
        echo 'bar';
    } else {
        echo "unknown $param";
    }
}
```